# Shiro.There is no session with id

Tags: session, gwt, shiro, subject

I am using shiro-1.2.3 for GWT webapp. I am able to configure the login process of the user; however, I need some help with the shiro's log out process. The webapp is deployed through tomcat and it creates new instance for different users. So, for instance, when two users are logged in, there are two session id created by shiro; however, when I click on the sign out button, it will call subject.logout() function to logout the user, it looks like that Shiro is keeping track of only one session ( the last user logged in), for some reason. It will logout successfully if there was only one user logged in; however, when logging out more than one, this is what I am getting:

> Caused by: org.apache.shiro.session.UnknownSessionException: There is no session with id [f5b7c3bf-2c53-40e9-a707-37f4265970aa]
>       at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.AbstractSessionDAO.readSession(AbstractSessionDAO.java:170)
>       at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.DefaultSessionManager.retrieveSessionFromDataSource(DefaultSessionManager.java:236)
>       at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.DefaultSessionManager.retrieveSession(DefaultSessionManager.java:222)
>       at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.AbstractValidatingSessionManager.doGetSession(AbstractValidatingSessionManager.java:118)
>       at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.AbstractNativeSessionManager.lookupSession(AbstractNativeSessionManager.java:105)
>       at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.AbstractNativeSessionManager.lookupRequiredSession(AbstractNativeSessionManager.java:109)
>       at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.AbstractNativeSessionManager.getAttribute(AbstractNativeSessionManager.java:206)
>       at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.DelegatingSession.getAttribute(DelegatingSession.java:141)
>       at org.apache.shiro.session.ProxiedSession.getAttribute(ProxiedSession.java:121)
>       at org.apache.shiro.session.ProxiedSession.getAttribute(ProxiedSession.java:121)
>       at org.apache.shiro.session.ProxiedSession.getAttribute(ProxiedSession.java:121)
>       at com.factorlab.security.FactorlabDelegatingSubject.getUser(FactorlabDelegatingSubject.java:34)
>       at com.factorlab.security.FactorlabDelegatingSubject.getUser(FactorlabDelegatingSubject.java:10)
>       at com.factorlab.persistence.AbstractEntityDao.getCurrentUser(AbstractEntityDao.java:227)
>       at com.factorlab.persistence.AbstractEntityDao.fireEvent(AbstractEntityDao.java:215)
>       at com.factorlab.persistence.AbstractEntityDao.saveOrUpdate(AbstractEntityDao.java:190)
>       at com.factorlab.persistence.AbstractEntityDao.saveOrUpdate(AbstractEntityDao.java:177)
>       at com.factorlab.persistence.AbstractEntityDao.saveOrUpdate(AbstractEntityDao.java:38)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor106.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
>       at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:196)
>       at $Proxy72.saveOrUpdate(Unknown Source)
>       at com.factorlab.observations.sales.OpportunityScoreUpdateServiceImpl.receiveOpportunityEvent(OpportunityScoreUpdateServiceImpl.java:83)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor103.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
>       at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
>       at $Proxy76.receiveOpportunityEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor102.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:69)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:84)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:57)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:102)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:102)
>       at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:126)
>       at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:227)
>       at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.process(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:127)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:73)
>       ... 49 more

```
**Shiro.ini**
[main]
myRealm=com.java.gwt.server.auth.MyRealm
myCacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager
securityManager.cacheManager = $myCacheManager 
securityManager.sessionManager.globalSessionTimeout = 9000000
```

I have also tried to use EhCache manager.

For login, I am using the same information as shown in the shiro's 10 minute tutorial.

**Thanks for your time.**

Comment: Shiro handles multiple sessions just fine, so there must be something else wrong. Are the login sessions from 2 totally separate browser instances? Can you also show your login code?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am following the same method for login as given in shiro's website. http://shiro.apache.org/10-minute-tutorial.html. I am not sure if I should configure anything else in shiro.ini file, this is what it looks like: [main]
 myRealm=com.java.lab.server.auth.MyRealm securityManager.sessionManager.globalSessionTimeout = 32400000
 myCacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager
 securityManager.cacheManager = $myCacheManager.

Comment: How are you testing the issue? Are you using two different browsers? Or perhaps you are using tabs within the same browser?

Comment: I am using two different browsers.

Comment: Are we talking about 1 user, or 2 really distinct users?

Comment: Two distinct users. Let's say if #1 user is logged in then on separate browser, #2 user will be logged in. Now if I log out #1 user, it will the there is no session id with xxx, as if it is expired or destroyed when #2 is logged in. If I logout #2, it will work fine since shiro has that session id.

Comment: This is very weird. Can you expand your question so it includes all the config and code related to shiro?

Comment: Since I want to use tomcat's container to manage sessions, I did not add anything in web.xml related to shiro. Let me know if you think I will need additional configuration in shiro.ini or anywhere else. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Is this all you have for shiro.ini?? Where are your users defined?